# What happens when the intermediate output does not fit in RAM in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I just started learning `Spark`. As per my understanding, `Spark` stores the intermediate output in RAM, so it is very fast compared to `Hadoop`. Correct me if I am wrong.

My question is, if my intermediate output is 2 GB and my free RAM is 1 GB, then what happens in this case? It may be a silly question, but I have not understood the in-memory concept of Spark. Can anyone please explain me the in-memory concept of Spark?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is asking about [RDD persistence](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) in Spark.

> You can mark an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache() methods on it. The first time it is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes. Spark’s cache is fault-tolerant – if any partition of an RDD is lost, it will automatically be recomputed using the transformations that originally created it.

Depending on how you set the storage level for an RDD, different outcomes can be configured. For example, if you set your storage level as `MEMORY_ONLY` (which is the default storage level), your output will store as much as it can in memory and recompute the rest of your RDD on the fly. You can persist your RDD and apply your storage level like the following: `rdd.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)`.

In your example case, 1GB of your output will be computed and in memory and the other 1GB will be computed when needed for a future step. There are other storage levels that can be set as well depending on your use case:

1. `MEMORY_AND_DISK` -- compute the entire RDD but spill some content to disk when necessary
2. `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` -- same as above but all elements are serialized
3. `DISK_ONLY` -- store all partitions straight to disk
4. `MEMORY_ONLY_2`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_2` -- same as above but partitions are replicated twice for more tolerance

Again, you have to look into your use case to figure out what is the best storage level. In some cases, recomputation of an RDD maybe actually be quicker than loading everything back from disk. In other cases, a fast serializer can get reduce the data grabbed from disk leading to a quick response with the data in question.

Comment: ex - I have 2TB data. I want to do word count on that data. So in word count we have two transformation, right. when creating RDD from one transformation to another transformation, it creates one RD to another RDD. second RDD stores data in memory, so if my RAM size is more not fit then this condition what will happen. may be wrong question. can you explain me the word count example.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I can reply with the following :

The *intermediate* or *temporary* storage directory is specified by the `spark.local.dir` configuration parameter when configuring the Spark context.

The `spark.local.dir` directory is to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output files and RDDs that get stored on disk. [[Ref. Spark Configuration.](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties)]

This should be on a fast, local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of multiple directories on different disks.

Nevertheless, the issue you are addressing here is also called RDD persistence. Among the basics that you should already know using Spark caching, there is also  what's referred to as the storage level of an RDD which allows different storage level.

This will allowe you, for example, to **persist the dataset on disk**, **persist it in memory but as serialized Java objects** (to save space), **replicate it across nodes**, or store it **off-heap in Tachyon** *(This last one is experimental)*. [More information here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence).

**Note:** These levels are set by passing a StorageLevel object (Scala, Java, Python) to `persist`. The `cache` method is a shorthand for using the default storage level, which is `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY` where Spark stores deserialized objects in memory.

So to answer your question now,

***if my intermediate output is 2 GB and my free RAM is 1 GB, then what happens in this case?***

*I say it depends on how you configure and tune your Spark (app,cluster).*

**Note:** The in-memory in Spark is similar to any in-memory system in the world concept-wise, the main aim is to avoid heavy and expensive IOs. Which also means, if I go back to your question that if you decided to persist on DISK per say, you'll be loosing performance. More on that in the official documentation referenced in the answer.

Comment: ex - I have 2TB data. I want to do word count on that data. So in word count we have two transformation, right. when creating RDD from one transformation to another transformation, it creates one RD to another RDD. second RDD stores data in memory, so if my RAM size is more not fit then this condition what will happen. may be wrong question. can you explain me the word count example.

Comment: It depends of the storage level you have chosen. Per example, if you decide to use the default. It will end up in OOM. If you decided to serialize and store serialized data in memory, it will also generate OOME but later on. And so on, like describe in the official documentation on RDD persistence. If you chose to store, nevertheless, you'll loose performance, but you might end up with a result by the end.

Comment: @zero323 can you look into quickly this for me please! (If there no bother ofc). (The other answer was kinda copied from my answer as well, is there something to do about it? I know you are the moderator thought but you might know better than me.)

Comment: Hey @eliasah, I can assure you that I did not copy your answer. I was posting at the same as you were (on a fairly long answer!) so I didn't see your answer by the time I had posted.

Comment: @RohanAletty it's just that my answer was posted 10 minutes before yours.

Comment: @eliasah Yes, 10 minutes is not a lot of time between posts though. I'm sure as a more experienced user you've seen this sort of thing happen before as well. I've only been posting on SO consistently for about a month and it's already happened to me a few times where an answer posted even a few hours after mine (with very similar content) gets accepted. Just the nature of forum based Q and A :)